# Can't retain grad on Tensor that has requires_grad=False, despite specifically setting it to true

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am attempting to create an nn.module in pytorch, the set_model_params is currently very messy but I'm attempting to set requires_grad to true so I am able to use retain_grad(), but no matter where I'm putting requires_grad=True, it's telling me it's false

```py
class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, depth):
        super(MyModule, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(28*28, 50)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(50,10)
        

    def forward(self, x):
            x = x.view(-1, 28*28)
            x = torch.tanh(self.linear1(x))
            return self.linear3(x).view(-1)
    
    def set_model_params(self, params_dict):
        self.linear1.weight.data = params_dict["W1"]
        self.linear1.weight.data.requires_grad=True
        self.linear1.weight.data.retain_grad()

        self.linear1.bias.data = params_dict["b1"]
        self.linear1.bias.data.requires_grad=True
        self.linear1.bias.data.retain_grad()

        self.linear3.weight.data = params_dict["W3"]
        self.linear3.weight.data.requires_grad = True
        self.linear3.weight.data.retain_grad()

        self.linear3.bias.data = params_dict["b3"]
        self.linear3.bias.data.requires_grad = True
        self.linear3.bias.data.retain_grad()
```

This is set because the maximum and minimum values of the neural network parameters will change later in the network. I also have requires_grad=True set here.

```py
def init_params_dict(d):
    params_dict = {
        "W1": torch.rand(50, 28 * 28, device="cuda", requires_grad=True) * (d * 2) - 1,
        "b1": torch.zeros(50, device="cuda", requires_grad=True),
        "W3": torch.rand(10, 50, device="cuda", requires_grad=True) * (d * 2) - 1,
        "b3": torch.zeros(10, device="cuda", requires_grad=True),
    }
    for i in range(8):
        params_dict['Wd' + str(i)] = torch.rand(50, 50, device="cuda", requires_grad=True) * (d * 2) - 1
        params_dict['bd' + str(i)] = torch.zeros(50, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)
    
    return params_dict

mymod = MyModule(8)
public_params = init_params_dict(0.01)

mymod.set_model_params(public_params)
```

Nonetheless, I get this error.

```
<ipython-input-88-52eb353b30c6> in set_model_params(self, params_dict)
     27         self.linear1.weight.data = params_dict["W1"]
     28         self.linear1.weight.data.requires_grad=True
---> 29         self.linear1.weight.data.retain_grad()
     30 
     31         self.linear1.bias.data = params_dict["b1"]

RuntimeError: can't retain_grad on Tensor that has requires_grad=False
```

How can I set requires_grad=True on one of these leaf variables and have it stick?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/layer-weight-vs-weight-data/24271/2